# Java - MDB - How to avoid concurrency issue

Tags: java, concurrency, message-queue

We have MDB implemented which take user input and processing parallel. We have a limit check on user data (like number of phone numbers user can have).

The problem I'm facing is two different threads pickup same user's data and it processes. first thread is fine and it checks limit and adds the phone to user profile correctly. Second thread also does the same. But the limit check happens before the first thread commits the transaction, so limit check is passed. But it crossed the limit.

Is there any way to fix? making one user's data picked by same thread is fine. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Edit: One more thing I missed to convey. This issue happens when its running in different nodes.

Comment: You have a concurrency problem not a parallel problem. You need some way of controlling who gets what, when. Without a lot more information there is nothing more I can add.

Comment: @edharned Thank you, I have updated question accordingly

Comment: Have a look at this pattern: http://www.eaipatterns.com/CompetingConsumers.html. Consider what would happen if the space of users were divided amongst the servers. Like, one server handles users whose account start 0-5, the other 6-9. Now you have SPOFs, but that can be addressed by using a lease mechanism where each lease represents a range, and servers grab leases as they start up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends from the Application Server, number of nodes and application, but the follwing scenarios are ok for me:

- Weblogic or JBOSS support **Unit of Order** feature:

> Message Unit-of-Order is a WebLogic Server value-added feature that
>   enables a stand alone message producer, or a group of producers acting
>   as one, to group messages into a single unit with respect to the
>   processing order. This single unit is called a Unit-of-Order and
>   requires that all messages from that unit be processed sequentially in
>   the order they were created.

- If you update the same record the first thread acquire the lock and the second thread wait the transaction commit, then the second thread should check the update (**optimistic lock**) and it could exit immediatly.

eg.

```
Thread 1: lastUpd = now() 
Thread 1: UPDATE MYTABLE SET LAST_UPDATE=${lastUpd} WHERE ID=${id}
Thread 2: lastUpd = now()
Thread 2: UPDATE MYTABLE SET LAST_UPDATE=${lastUpd} WHERE ID=${id} //remain locked
Thread 1: a lot of work ...
Thread 1 COMMIT
Thread 2: a lot of work ...
Thread 2: lastUpd2= SELECT LAST_UPDATE MYTABLE WHERE ID=${id}
Thread 2: IF lastUpd2!= lastUpd ROLLBACK
```

Comment: I don't know how Unit of Order feature has to be implemented. Could you please give some links or information? Thank you.

Comment: You do not need to implement nothing, just configure weblogic and put the uuid on the message's header:http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/jms/uoo.html

Comment: I am going to use programmatically as the same queue is used in for different messages too. Thank you

Comment: I tried and it seems to be working, no duplicate issue. But messages with same UOO went to different node in cluster environment. Is it expected?